# Accept YAML input from website user

Tags: python, security, yaml

I haven't written this in the code yet but I want to parse YAML from my website users. The YAML should just be string key/values and lists of strings.

They input YAML into a textbox, send it to the server, then the python will parse the YAML, put it in the database and it will later be queryable.

Is there anything I need to do to be able to safely do the above?

Comment: Is this a simple `key: value` type of YAML or does it include nested structures too ?

Comment: It can contain nested structure

Comment: You can try to parse lines with `:` and if `-` exists in the next line append it to the parent structure. Also use `strip()` in order to remove unwanted spaces.

Comment: Although YAML is one of the more intuitive formats, I suggest you warn your users that some strings have special meanings if not quoted (`true`, `nill`, integers, dates, etc), and that some characters cannot be used at the beginning of a string without quoting. If you use PyYAML this is worse (it only supports YAML 1.1 where `on`, `off`, `yes`, `no` in various forms are booleans and need quoting. You could e.g. populate the textbox with (commented out) examples of what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to observe is to parse the yaml with either `safe_load` ( [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (supporting YAML 1.2), [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) (YAML 1.1)) or `round_trip_load` (ruamel.yaml, this will allow you to extract comments in the YAML file if necessary).

The normal `load` could be used to execute programs by the Python interpreter, unless you pre-process the YAML to remove any tags.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of ruamel.yaml</sub>